# Iterate through pandas df rows to calculate a new variable depending on conditions

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
dict1 = {'category': {0: 0.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 0.0},
 'Id': {0: 24108, 1: 24307, 2: 24307, 3: 24411, 4: 24411},
 'count': {0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 33, 3: 98, 4: 33},
 'weight': {0: 0.5, 1: 0.2, 2: 0.7, 3: 1.2, 4: 0.39}}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)

    category    Id  count   weight
0   0.0      24108    3     0.50
1   1.0      24307    2     0.20
2   0.0      24307   33     0.70
3   1.0      24411   98     1.20
4   0.0      24411   33     0.39
```

There are about 1000 such entries. Some only have 1 `category` tag, as is the example for `Id 24108`. Other Ids have two entries because there are two `category` tags, such as `Id` 24307 and 24411.

I want to generate a new column called `val` that follows one of 3 rules, depending on certain conditions.

If an `Id` only has 1 tag associated with it, such as `Id 24108`, then the value in the new column `val` should be a simple product between `count` and `weight`.

If an `Id` has 2 tags, such as `Id` 24307 or 24411, then the script should look at which one of the two entries has a larger `count` value first.

For `Id` 24307, the count for `category` 0 is higher than the count for `category` 1, therefore the `val` column should be 2 * (0.2+1) next to `category` 1 and 33 * (1-0.7) next to `category` 0

For `Id` 24411, the count for `category` 0 is lower than the count for `category` 1, therefore the `val` column should be 98 * (1-1.2) next to `category` 1 and 33 * (0.3+1) next to `category` 0.

The expected output should be like this:

```
    category    Id  count   weight  val
0   0.0      24108    3     0.50   1.50
1   1.0      24307    2     0.20   2.40
2   0.0      24307   33     0.70   9.90
3   1.0      24411   98     1.20 -19.60
4   0.0      24411   33     0.39  42.90
```

Comment: is it guranteed that there will be atmost two category(0 and 1) for every Id?

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar Yes, only those two categories exist in the data

Comment: What have you tried before asking? Also, the logic is not complete: what happens if there are more than 2 rows for the same `Id`? What if an `Id` has several rows with the same category?

Comment: @PierreD there are only max two rows for each ```Id```, otherwise I would've mentioned.

Comment: as a general rule of thumb, I don't like to assume conditions or circumstances based on unsaid assumptions. In fact, I often `assert` for conditions I just "know" "must" be true. That has saved my butt countless number of times and is part of [defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming). With a bit of practice, it becomes second nature to envision some of the things that could go wrong and test against them. It will make your code more resilient in the long run.

Comment: What's supposed to happen if an `Id` has two rows with the same `count`? For example, if your row 3 had a `count` of `33`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use boolean arithmetics and `numpy.select`:

```
g = df1.groupby('Id')

# number of categories
n = g['category'].transform('nunique')
# max count
m = g['count'].transform('max')

# selection based on conditions
df1['val'] = np.select(
          [n.eq(1), df1['count'].eq(m)], # case if unique, case if max
          # formula for unique, formula for max
          [df1['count']*df1['weight'], df1['count']*(1-df1['weight'])],
          # default value (i.e. not unique and non-max count)
          df1['count']*(1+df1['weight'])
         )
```

output:

```
   category     Id  count  weight    val
0       0.0  24108      3    0.50   1.50
1       1.0  24307      2    0.20   2.40
2       0.0  24307     33    0.70   9.90
3       1.0  24411     98    1.20 -19.60
4       0.0  24411     33    0.39  45.87
```

If you really have only 2 categories, then you can simplify the arithmetic to consider the non max as min. It's <strike>a bit</strike> quite hacky but should work fine:

```
g = df1.groupby('Id')

# 0 if unique category else 1
n = g['category'].transform('nunique').gt(1).astype(int)
# -1 if count is min of group else 1
m = (df1['count'] != g['count'].transform('min'))*2-1

df1['val'] = df1['count'] * (n-m*df1['weight'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```py
gbct = df1.groupby('Id')['count'].transform
df1['val'] = df1['count'] * (gbct('size') - 1 + 
                             (3 - 2*gbct('rank', 'first')) * df1['weight'])
```

**Assumptions**

- There are only 1-row or 2-row groups per `Id`.
- That's it (e.g.: `count` can be the same for two rows of an `Id` --in which case the first row will get the `count * (1 + weight)` value and the other will get `count * (1 - weight)`).

**Explanation**

Consider this:

```py
>>> df1.assign(
    a=gbct('size') - 1,
    s=3 - 2*gbct('rank', 'first'),
    val=df1['count'] * (gbct('size') - 1 + (3 - 2*gbct('rank', 'first')) * df1['weight'])
)
   category     Id  count  weight  a    s    val
0       0.0  24108      3    0.50  0  1.0   1.50
1       1.0  24307      2    0.20  1  1.0   2.40
2       0.0  24307     33    0.70  1 -1.0   9.90
3       1.0  24411     98    1.20  1 -1.0 -19.60
4       0.0  24411     33    0.39  1  1.0  45.87
```

In the above, `a` is 1 for 2-row `Id`s and 0 for single row ones. `s` is a sign for `weight`. The formula for `val` is then simply:

```
val = count * (a + s * weight)
```

Note what happens if an `Id` has the same count for each row:

```py
>>> tmp = df1.copy()
>>> tmp.loc[3, 'count'] = 33
>>> gbct = tmp.groupby('Id')['count'].transform
>>> tmp.assign(
...     a=gbct('size') - 1,
...     s=3 - 2*gbct('rank', 'first'),
...     val=tmp['count'] * (gbct('size') - 1 +
...                         (3 - 2*gbct('rank', 'first')) * tmp['weight'])
... )
   category     Id  count  weight  a    s    val
0       0.0  24108      3    0.50  0  1.0   1.50
1       1.0  24307      2    0.20  1  1.0   2.40
2       0.0  24307     33    0.70  1 -1.0   9.90
3       1.0  24411     33    1.20  1  1.0  72.60
4       0.0  24411     33    0.39  1 -1.0  20.13
```

Comment: Nice one with `rank` ;)